# As the scrollbar scrolls, the visibility of the labels gets messy in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datagrid, devexpress

The visibility of my labels in the datagridd changes according to being true false by binding with property. As the scrollbar scrolls (because it is not fully loaded), the labels get mixed up, what is the reason?

----------------------XAML---------------------------------------------------

```
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Elementler}" Margin="33,10,10,10" x:Name="dataGridSonuc" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFCCCCCC" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#f0f0f0"/>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Göster" Width="15*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"  IsChecked="{Binding Show, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Click="CheckBox_Click" />
                            <Button  Height="18"  x:Name="buttonShow"  Width="23"  Click="buttonShow_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Image>
                                        <Image.Style>
                                            <Style>
                                                <Setter  Property="Image.Source" Value="/Resources/Images/code.png" />
                                            </Style>
                                        </Image.Style>
                                    </Image>
                                </Grid>
                            </Button>
                            <Label Height="Auto" Content="*" Name="ShowLabel" DataContext="{Binding Show}" Visibility="Hidden" Foreground="Red"  Loaded="ShowLabel_Loaded"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Salt Okunur" Width="15.5*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"  IsChecked="{Binding ReadOnly, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Click="CheckBox_Click" />
                            <Button  Height="18"  x:Name="buttonEnabled"  Width="24" Click="buttonEnabled_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Image>
                                        <Image.Style>
                                            <Style>
                                                <Setter  Property="Image.Source" Value="/Resources/Images/code.png" />
                                            </Style>
                                        </Image.Style>
                                    </Image>
                                </Grid>
                            </Button>
                            <Label Height="Auto" Content="*" Name="EnableLabel" DataContext="{Binding ReadOnly}" Visibility="Hidden"  Foreground="Red" Loaded="EnableLabel_Loaded" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Zorunlu" Width="15*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"  IsChecked="{Binding Required, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Click="CheckBox_Click" />
                            <Button  Height="18"  x:Name="buttonRequired"  Width="24" Click="buttonRequired_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Image>
                                        <Image.Style>
                                            <Style>
                                                <Setter  Property="Image.Source" Value="/Resources/Images/code.png" />
                                            </Style>
                                        </Image.Style>
                                    </Image>
                                </Grid>
                            </Button>
                            <Label Height="Auto" Content="*" Name="RequiredLabel" DataContext="{Binding Required}" Visibility="Hidden"  Foreground="Red" Loaded="RequiredLabel_Loaded" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Alan Adı" Width="55*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock Padding="2"  Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

-------------------------------------XMAL.CS---------------------------------------------

```
    private void ShowLabel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {
        (sender as Label).Visibility = (bool)((sender as Label).DataContext) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;

    }

    private void EnableLabel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as Label).Visibility = (bool)((sender as Label).DataContext) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;

    }

    private void RequiredLabel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as Label).Visibility = (bool)((sender as Label).DataContext) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

Comment: Could you share your view models and explain how they are inteded to work?

Comment: You should add the definition of the `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` in `DataGrid.Resources`, `<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="b2v" />`, and bind it like this: `Visibility="{Binding Path=Show, Converter={StaticResource b2v}}"`. Remove the `DataContext` binding and `Loaded` event handling.